# Error when trying to print PDF generated using rsvg-convert

Tags: pdf, inkscape, svg

I'm trying to create an A3 PDF from an SVG file on the command line in Ubuntu. The Conversion works great and looks spot on. However, when I try to print the PDF in Adobe Acrobat I get the error:

> An error exists on this page. Acrobat may not display the page correctly. Please contact the person who created the PDF document to correct the problem

To convert the SVG to PDF I use:

`rsvg-convert -d 300 -w 842 -h 1190 -f pdf input.svg > output.pdf`

I've tried ImageMagick and Inkscape too. Inkscape gives the same error. ImageMagick doesn't give the error but I can't seem to get a 300dpi PDF at A3! The always come put tiny or blurry !!

Any help would be massively appreciated :) I don't mind which O use (rsvg-convert, Ink Scape or Image Magick) as long as I get the results

Thanks